# Update silverstripe-linkable Object after import

Tags: php, silverstripe, oembed

I'm using [silverstripe-linkable](https://github.com/sheadawson/silverstripe-linkable) to display product videos. After importing a Product via CsvBulkLoader, the link SourceURL is set but the external file is not embeded. Is there a way to do embed this programmatically?

That's my code

```
  public static function importVideo(&$obj, $val, $record) {
    if($val != 'EmbeddedObject') {
      $obj->Video()->SourceURL = $val;
      $obj->Video()->write();
      $obj->Video()->updateEmbedHTML();
      $obj->Video()->write();
    }
  }
```

I've already tried calling

```
$obj->Video()->updateEmbedHTML();
```

or

```
$obj->Video()->Embed();
```

any suggestions?

Comment: You can simplify your code with `$obj->Video()->setFromUrl($val);` then write it. But to check for your issue please ensure that link is actually correct: `$embed = Embed\Embed::create($val);` $embed should not be null.

Comment: using setFromUrl leads to an error `Call to a member function CreatedCount() on null`

Comment: Probably consider asking for help in the repo's issue manager if you feel like it's lacking clarity.